# Dead Letter Queue not being created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

my exchange and dlq are not being created.  I have the following in my YML below.  I do get an anonymous queue created, but no messages are posted either.  Any thoughts.

```
  rabbit:
    bindings:
      documentrequest-policyinqadapter:
        producer:
          bindingRoutingKey: documentrequest.adapter.*.*.*.policyinq.req
          routing-key-expression: headers['events-type']
        consumer:
          autoBindDlq: true
          republishToDlq: true
          requeueRejected: false
          bindingRoutingKey: documentrequest.adapter.*.*.*.policyinq.req
          deadLetterQueueName: pi-adapter-dead-letter-queue
          deadLetterExchange: PI-DocumentRequestService-AdapterService-Exchange-dlx
          deadLetterRoutingKey: documentrequest.adapter.*.*.*.policyinq.req
          maxAttempts: 1
          maxConcurrency: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Dead letter queues are not supported with anonymous subscriptions; you must add a `group` to the consumer binding.

Comment: Would it be consumer:  .group:   myGroup   ?   (sorry, this is very new to me)

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.documentrequest-policyinqadapter.group: someGroup`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_common_binding_properties and https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#consumer-groups `>By default, when a group is not specified, Spring Cloud Stream assigns the application to an anonymous and independent single-member consumer group that is in a publish-subscribe relationship with all other consumer groups.`